# Several arguments for re.compile in Python?

Tags: python, regex, csv

To follow up [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59173183/searching-for-a-specific-phrase-in-csv-file-using-regex-in-python/59196029#59196029), I'd like to ask if it's possible to add several arguments while using re.compile? 
I took "global warming" as an example in my previous question. What if I want to search for possible forms of "global warming" and also "climate change" in my database? 
Any solutions to that?

Comment: related: [Regex Alternation Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783053/regex-alternation-order) ... [Python regex: Alternation for sets of words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284334/python-regex-alternation-for-sets-of-words) ... [Questions tagged regex-alternation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-alternation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using this: `(global warming|climate change)`!

`|` is separating the various options you have.